# How I can use light to control of amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, circuit-design, control, electron

I want to make a car that I can control by light, and I thought of using a photoresistor and a light sensor to control the amplifier to make it perform two functions.

The first function is to make the car move with a red light, and the second function is to make the car lift things with another light, such as a green light.

My doctor told me I could use a physics filter to make it easier to control.

What steps should I follow to design the circuit? How can I use the physics filter?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are talking about a miniature size toy. If it was full size truck and you had the money and tools to build it you could be stamped to be a too dangerous person to be let stay free.

Controlling a toy: You cannot compete with daylight which has all colors mixed together. Better to use some pulsed modulation like it's done in common infrared remote controllers. They would work well also with visible light transmitting and signal detecting components if the light is strong enough and the distance is short enough and there's no visibility obstacles. Radio remote controllers like the common car door key could also be useful. Daylight doesn't affect at all. Numerous toys are already available with radio remote controllers. Full remote control systems are sold to hobby toy builders. They contain as well the transmitter, the receiver and even some servo motors and relays to control or do the actual work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'd use two different photo-detectors (can be LDR, phototransistor/photodiode or even a module) side-by-side, place optical filters  - red in front of one of them and green for another.

When they both exposed to green light, red filter will not allow any flux lines to the sensor (because red and green are not neighbours in the spectrum) so only green one will detect light. Likewise, when both of them are exposed to red light, green sensor will not pass anything so only the red one will detect light.

The problem here is that the daylight has all of the colours (red, orange, yellow, green, blue, purple) so if you run the thing under sunlight there's a risk of having both sensors detecting.